# Upgrading from Angular 9 to 11 prevents router.navigate from loading new component

Tags: angular, observable, angular-router

I updated my project from Angular 9 to 11 (upgrading to 10 along the way). It broke routing in a strange way--the below method works fine in 9, but in 11, you can see the url change to upload , but the page doesn't actually redirect/render the upload component. It's reaching into the finalize and subscribe  blocks fine, and no errors in the console. The HTTP request in the auth service comes back fine too. I didn't see anything in the Angular upgrade documentation about observables needing to be handled differently.

```
  login(userType?: string): void {
    this.isLoading = true;
    const login$ = this.authService.login(userType);
    login$
      .pipe(
        finalize(() => {
          blah blah
        }),
        untilDestroyed(this)
      )
      .subscribe(
        () => {
          this.router.navigate([this.route.snapshot.queryParams.redirect || '/upload'], { replaceUrl: true });
        },
        (error) => {
          log.debug(`Login Error: ${error}`);
          this.error = error;
        }
      );
  }
```

Comment: Without seeing how the code is embedded I don't think we can help much. One random guess: I know this behavior occurs when a resolver returns an Observable that emits, but does not complete. So maybe the /upload route has a non completing resolver?

Comment: I have the same exact problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I figured it. From https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=10.2-11.0 you need to check this point:

> If you use the Router's RouteReuseStrategy, the argument order has
> changed. **When calling RouteReuseStrategy#shouldReuseRoute previously
> when evaluating child routes, they would be called with the future and
> current arguments swapped.** If your RouteReuseStrategy relies
> specifically on only the future or current snapshot state, you may
> need to update the shouldReuseRoute implementation's use of future and
> current ActivateRouteSnapshots.

So open your `RouteReuseStrategy` and change:

```
shouldReuseRoute(current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean
```

to

```
shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, current: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean
```

This fix the redirection after login for me, but now my logout redirection generate multiple JS errors...

Answer (score 1):

Pasting response from the GitHub issue:

@lebesnec - There was a bug in the router where these *were* swapped but they no longer are (https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/3817e5f1dfeb9de26fa2ea4068a37565f435214f#diff-a655d62becd522d808a607905e22b79610a910364071ae8e1fc9c57714900463). `future` should always be the first param. If you're seeing something different, please provide a reproduction in stackblitz or a github repo.

To clarify, the previous code would sometimes the future snapshot into the second argument position so `curr` would be the future snapshot and vice versa. The new behavior is that `future` is always the future snapshot and `curr` is the current one.

It's a bit hard to tell from the snippet in the GitHub repo, but I think the update to your code should be this:

```
  public shouldReuseRoute(future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): boolean {
    return (future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig) || curr.data.reuse;
  }
```

Logically, this seems to make sense. Reuse the route if the *current* snapshot has the `data.reuse`.

Rather than swapping your parameters in the function declaration (which would no longer match the Angular implementation), your *logic* in the function needs to be updated because `future` *used to be* the current snapshot, before the fix in the Angular router code.